Manwha where fl is isekai into a novel and is adopted daughter but real daughter was alive
May be a recent release, most likely tapas or webtoon. Or less likely Tappytoon or Manta.
There is a female lead who came from our world and isekai into either a novel or a game. She is adopted, possibly off the street by a duke or similar. Theit daughter is ill but still alive. I remember people in the comments saying that he should have just waited until if the daughter after to adopt another child. Not sure but there may have been jealousy from the original daughter. There may have also been a saint who was well evil. Or maybe we just think she's evil. Pretty sure there was a brother there too
Likely in RF if it was a tapas. May be a recentish release

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Unsure about hair colour. I don't think its white blonde like the Silksia manwha. I do feel like if there was an evil saint maybe she had red or yellow hair? I think the og fl from novel may have been blonde
